# Placing texture in the right place on the object

Tags: texture, packaging, cinema4d, adobe-dimension

I have been stuck with .c4d I got from another designer.
On a "stand up pouch" packaging (here on example), I am stuck with a kind of spherical projection, and can't find the right way to "apply" the texture correctly on the object.

Would you know where to begin?

[image: Screenshot of my window]

Comment: I suggest you get some basic C4D tutorials first, it's really not the same as Keyshot or Dimension. Perhaps contact the previous designer if you're in a hurry to finish this project.

Comment: Ok understood, I will un-personalise the question, sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

After some research, [this tutorial](https://www.cineversity.com/vidplaytut/cinema_4d_lite_reference_placing_textures_exactly_on_objects) is the most efficient I could find on the subject.

In synthesis :

- Select object
- Right hand menu > texture tag > tag > projection In my case "flat" was appropriate
- Right hand menu > texture tag > coordinates > adjust as necessary

[image]